# Unable to connect to local PostgreSQL database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I created a simple rails application:

**1**

> $ rails new myapp1 -d postrgresql

**2**. Removed `/public/index.html`

**3**. Created the Homecontroller and the actions

**4**. Wrote the routes

> myapp1::Application.routes.draw do
>
> ```
>   root :to => "home#index"
>   match 'about' => 'home#about'
>   match 'contacts' => 'home#contacts'
>   match 'projects' => 'home#projects'
> end
> ```

**5**. Created the views and the default layout

**6**. The bottom line. Here is the database.yml

> development:
>
> ```
>   adapter: postgresql
>   encoding: unicode
>   database: myapp1_db
>   host: localhost
>   pool: 5
>   username: myapp1_user
>   password: 1234
>  
> test:
>   adapter: postgresql
>     encoding: unicode
>     database: myapp1_db
>     host: localhost
>     pool: 5
>     username: myapp1_user
>     password: 1234
>
> production:
>   adapter: postgresql
>     encoding: unicode
>     database: myapp1_db
>     host: localhost
>     pool: 5
>     username: myapp1_user
>     password: 1234
> ```

and of course I created user and database

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \password
postgres=# create user myapp1_user with password '1234';
postgres=# create database myapp1_db owner myapp1_user;
```

But there are some worries:

**1**. Now I don't use any database, but in spite of this the application gives an error

> PG::Error FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "myapp1"

**2**. It seems like rails turns a blind eye to `database.yml`. Why does it use the user **myapp1** instead of **myapp1_user**?

Comment: Make sure you add port as well in the config it either 5432 or 5433 check using 'lsof' command to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace is significant in YAML.

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    ...
    password: 1234
```

Should be:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  ...
  password: 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide host and port in the database.yml file, like this:

```
    development:
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      database: myapp1_db
      host: localhost
      pool: 5
      username: myapp1_user
      password: 1234
      host: localhost
      port: 5432
```

Works like a charm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Rails 3.2.x and PostgreSQL 9.1.x